# Change SKU to a custom field in order processing email notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On each email notification sent out to a customer telling them their order is being processed (assuming SKUs are enabled) it will display the SKU next to the product name in parenthesis. I want it to display a custom field in this case Item ID, which is different from the SKU.

I have gone into the customer-processing-order.php file and tried to get the meta after the title, however this only throws out the id # of that array instead of displaying that field's data. For example in that template below we have:

```
<tr>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
</tr>
```

If you change this to something like:

```
<tr>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <?php the_field('item_id'); ?></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
</tr>
```

It just displays that array ID instead of the actual field output. I'd like to find a cleaner method altogether where I can just throw this into a function file, but I can't find any solutions.

Comment: when you say "It just displays that array ID" do you mean an integer? is the_field('item_id') returning an array? If so, do you always want the same element in the array?

Comment: Yes and yes. I always want it to display what is in the "item id" field for the product ordered. So if they bought two different items they'd both have their own unique item id pulled from that meta field.

Comment: can you paste in the output of print_r(the_field('item_id')) ?

Comment: It just outputs "109934," but that number varies per product, based on what the product ID value is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `_e( 'sku:', 'woocommerce' );` to output the SKU?

HTH,

=C=